# How to global error filter on Spring WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webclient

I want to add a global error filter to my `WebClient`, so that **any** exceptions and responses that are not `200 OK` result in an exception.

Problem: the following already works, but in case the url host connection is down completely (`java.net.ConnectException`), then the filter does not execute at all:

```
WebClient.Builder builder;
builder.filter(errorFilter());

public static ExchangeFilterFunction errorFilter() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
        if (!clientResponse.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
            return Mono.error(new MyCustomException());
        }

        return Mono.just(clientResponse);
    });
}
```

Usage:
`webClient.post().syncBody(body).retrieve().block();`

Question: how can I add a global error filter here that also catches those type of exceptions?